# Failure using sed to filter page

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I am using sed to try filter a file

The item I am trying to obtain is

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENT (columns) VALUES ('','','')
```

This is the query that I am using

```
sed -n '/INSERT INTO PAYMENT/,/)/p'  axpayments.txt
```

Now the problem is this gets me

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENT (columns)
```

I need the entire string.

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENT (columns) VALUES ('','','')
```

Okay so what I am trying to do is this

sed -n '/INSERT INTO PAYMENT/,/')/p'  axpayments.txt

This throws an error because of the quote.
The problem is that there are multiple lines for each query. That is why I need to get from the beginning "INSERT INTO PAYMENT" to the end which is " ') "

Comment: Does your input above show a complete line?

Comment: The lines in the file are as follows "INSERT INTO ax_payment *newline* (column*newline*column) *newline* VALUES *newline*('val'*newline*,'val',*newline*'val')"

Comment: The return from above is INSERT INTO ax_payment newline (column*newline*column) without the values

Comment: Please edit your question. It is hard to understand the input from a comment.

Comment: 1) what is ax_payment (a variable) ? 2) the `)`is on the same line as the `insert` so your address range will not work as expected (it take the first `)` on a following line, not the same.

Comment: I think you need only `sed -n '/INSERT INTO/,/)/p'  axpayments.txt`

Comment: I have changed my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed -n '/INSERT INTO ax_payment/{:loop; N; /VALUES.*)/{p;d}; b loop}' yourfile.txt
```